# Setting column names in a pandas dataframe (Python)

Tags: python, dataframe

When setting a column name for a pandas dataframe, why does the following work:

```
df_coeff = pd.DataFrame(data = lm.coef_, index = X.columns, columns = ['Coefficient'])
```

While this does not work

```
df_coeff = pd.DataFrame(data = lm.coef_, index = X.columns, columns = 'Coefficient')
```

Why are brackets required around the column name? What is Python doing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`DataFrame` constructor](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) expects an *"Index or array-like"* as the `column` argument.

- `['Coefficient']` is a [Python list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) with a single entry, the string `'Coefficient'`.
- `'Coefficient'` is not a list, but just a [string](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings).

`DataFrame` accepts a Python list, but not a string, as an *array-like*.