# Python list to .csv

Tags: python, pandas

I create a list like this my_list=[('a','b',1,2),('a1,'b',1,2)]
i want it to dump to a .csv file with headers

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame(dis)
my_df.to_csv('E:\list.csv' ,header=['col1','col2','col3','col4'],index=False)
```

but after running my code, The csv file does not have any headers,but instead of it it is showing indexes

output:

```
 0 1 2 3
 a b 1 2
a1 b 1 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define columns names in `DataFrame` constructor:

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame(dis, columns=['col1','col2','col3','col4'])
my_df.to_csv('E:\list.csv', index=False)
```

EDIT:

In last version of pandas, `0.22.0` your solution also working very nice, so the best is upgrade pandas:

```
my_list=[('a','b',1,2),('a1','b',1,2)]
my_df = pd.DataFrame(my_list)
print (my_df)
    0  1  2  3
0   a  b  1  2
1  a1  b  1  2

print(my_df.to_csv(header=['col1','col2','col3','col4'],index=False))
col1,col2,col3,col4
a,b,1,2
a1,b,1,2
```

EDIT: Thanks [Dawid Dave Kosiński](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48091106/python-list-to-csv#comment83156927_48091129) for another solution:

import csv

```
my_list=[('a','b',1,2),('a1','b',1,2)]
cols = ['col1','col2','col3','col4']

with open('list.csv','w') as out:
    csv_out = csv.writer(out)
    csv_out.writerow(cols)
    for row in my_list:
        csv_out.writerow(row)
```

Comment: [Dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44700244/setting-column-names-in-a-pandas-dataframe-python), you think?

Comment: You could test the csv module in python https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: @DawidDaveKosiński - thank you, I add it to answer also.